# Drupal White Screen of Death

Tags: drupal, wsod

I get the WSOD when i login as an admin.

My site works fine for users.
But as an admin, when I login, I get a blank screen.
I can go direct to different sections of the admin console by using the direct link.

I have tried changing the php limits, disabling the Devel module, checking the error logs.
But with no luck.

Tried changing themes too.

Kind of ran other out of ideas.

Any suggestions that I can try?

Thanks

Comment: Which logs did you check? Drupal's, or the webserver's? WSOD + a 500 error almost always means there's an error message somewhere. WSOD + a 200 response code would point more towards you breaking a theme.

Comment: I was checking the Drupal error logs. I just checked the servers error log and i see a lot of PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in /home/artworldpod/public_html/includes/common.inc on line 2255.

That said, i get a WSOD + 200 response code. I will try looking into the themes again.